# Diigo not showing imported bookmarks tags?

Tags: delicious, bookmarks, diigo

Anyone having this problem?

After I imported my Delicious bookmarks into Diigo, I can browse all the bookmarks, but I don't see any of my tags listed.

Common problem?

Should I just wait a bit more or is there a way to 'update' Diigo tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they just showed up... so, I guess all I had to do was just wait for a few day.. sweet =)